# Flutter Video player not playing in ios

Tags: flutter, flutter-ios, flutter-video-player

I am using video_player package to play videos from network in flutter. It works fine in android, but fails to load in ios.

> **Flutter 3.3.3**
>
> **video_player: ^2.4.7**

PS: Server call is **https**, Issue is happening in **real device** and Response header has **Accept-Ranges : bytes**

Request

> connection: close
>
> access-control-allow-origin: *
>
> accept: */*
>
> accept-encoding: identity
>
> accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
>
> access-control-allow-credentials: true
>
> range: bytes=0-1

Server side response

> accept: application/pdf,application/octet-stream   accept-ranges:
> bytes   cache-control: no-cache,no-store,max-age=0,must-revalidate
> connection: keep-alive   content-disposition: inline;
> filename="DeviceMediaActivity_99966.MOV"
> content-length: 1706570   content-type: application/octet-stream
> date: Fri,14 Oct 2022 04:28:14 GMT   expires: 0   keep-alive:
> timeout=60   pragma: no-cache   vary:
> Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers
> x-content-type-options: nosniff   x-frame-options: DENY
> x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block

Comment: same problem here

Comment: same here , working fine in android and any video from other sites , the issue only in iOS